Randomness of thread mutex locking
In C++ I have a multithreaded program where the basic idea is to assign persons to cars. Every car is a resource that a thread - person, is locking. My program allows me to add a number of persons that will eventually lock a car while the programm is running.
I'm wondering if it's normal that when I add 50 people and after that I add another 30 people it looks like the 30 people are being assigned to the cars after all the 50 people are assigned. As far as I know the operating system decides which thread has higher priority.
It looks like this:
50  <- adding 50 persons
person from group: 50 added to car: 0
person from group: 50 added to car: 1
20  <- adding 20 persons
person from group: 50 added to car: 2
.
.
.
(all persons from group 50 were assigned to the cars)
person from group: 20 added to car: 0
person from group: 20 added to car: 1
person from group: 20 added to car: 2
.
.
Is it possible to "mix" the assignment of the threads so no matter when I add a person he can still be assigned before the person that was in the group I've added previously?
So it would look like this:
50  <- adding 50 persons
person from group: 50 added to car: 0
person from group: 50 added to car: 1
20  <- adding 20 persons
person from group: 50 added to car: 2
person from group: 20 added to car: 3
person from group: 20 added to car: 4
person from group: 50 added to car: 0
person from group: 20 added to car: 1
person from group: 50 added to car: 2
.
.
.

int numberOfCars = 5;
int numberOfPersons;
bool typed = false;

void addPersons(int numberOfPersons)
{
    std::vector<Person> persons = makePersons(numberOfPersons);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
        int carId = i % numberOfCars;
        threads.emplace_back(
            [carId, person = std::move(person[i])]() mutable {
                car[carId].addPerson(person);
            });
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
}

void userInput()
{
    while (true) {
        std::string inputVal;
        std::cin >> inputVal;
        numberOfPersons = inputVal;
        typed = true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread inputThread(userInput);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCars : i++)
        car.setId(i + 1);

    while (true) {
        if (typed) {
            typed = false;
            std::thread(addPerson, numberOfPersons).detach();
        }
    }

    inputThread.join();
    return 0;
}

I tried using detach() function but it didn't work as expected.
Edit:
The below is my addPerson function and locking & unlocking mutex functions.
void Car::lockCar() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(carMutex);
    carFreeCV.wait(lock, [this]() { return isFree; });
    isFree = false;
}

void Car::unlockCar()
{ 
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(carMutex);
        isFree = true;
    }
    carFreeCV.notify_one();
}

void Car::addPerson(Person& person) {
    lockCar();
    std::cout << "Person: " << person.name() << " added to car: " << id;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2);
    unlockCar();
}


please show a [mre]. If you're asking if std::mutex locking is fair, it isn't

I'd remove the I tried using detach() function but it didn't work as expected. unless you follow it by describing what you expected and what actually happened. In general, never write "It didn't work" or any variant unless you explain how it didn't work because we have to start guessing at what the problem was. We can make some really good guesses, especially if the presented code only has one mistake and is clearly documented, but some future asker with less experience may not be able to draw the same connection between question and answer and learn nothing.

"...  in the group I've added previously?" - "Previously" requires synchronization between the threads. I don't see any in your code. The whole thing has "race condition" written all over it. Please show a [mre] as Alan already asked for.

Side note: detach is rarely the right solution to a problem as it's effectively you-the-programmer abdicating all responsibility for the thread. Only detach if you do not care what happens to the thread, including it not completing before the program exits.

You can not and should not rely on the order of concurrent actions, this includes threads starting/completing, mutex locking/unlocking, condition variable notifications, etc. I don't know why you need threads in your program to begin with; an event-based approach in this type of program would be way easier.

Where's the mutex in this code?

Below is a comment, not intended to answer your question. I made it an "answer" because "comments" cannot display formatted code.

Your inputThread serves no purpose because it works in complete synchrony with the main thread. You never allow the inputThread and the main thread to do any interesting things concurrently with each other. Threads serve no purpose without concurrency.
You could slightly improve the program if you would;

get rid of the typed global variable,
get rid of the numberOfPersons global variable,
get rid of the userInput function, and
change main to look like this:

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCars : i++)
        car.setId(i + 1);

    while (true) {
        int numberOfPersons;
        std::cin >> numberOfPersons;
        std::thread(addPerson, numberOfPersons).detach();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


This can be solved with a producer-consumer pattern preferably with more consumers than producers (threads).
If each car had a lock and each person had a thread, the program wouldn't scale well beyond 1000-10000 threads due to limited resources on OS. What if 10 million people need to join the program? 10 million threads' creation overhead would be something like 100 seconds.
Instead of having a separate thread per person, it would be much more efficient to have task objects per person and run the tasks from a randomly-samplable pool of tasks, in dedicated threads per cpu core(or 2 with SMT). Add as many tasks as you want, and it would still give equal chance to sample any one of them, assuming randomness is fair enough.
Something like this in each consumer thread:
while(working)
{
    // random-sampling from vector or map
    auto task = pool.popRandomTask();
    if(task.type == Task::Runnable)
    {
         task.run();
    }
    else if(task.type == Task::End)
    {
         working = false;
    }
}

then this in producer thread:
while(people.size()>0)
{
    // simply adding new elements to a vector or a map
    pool.pushTask(people.popTask());
}

std::mt19937 should be good enough to compute the randomness within a boundary like 0-to-N-1 where N is current size of pool.

If you insist on 1 thread per person:

put all person-threads on wait / sleep indefinitely
generate a random number
notify(wake up) the person-thread with that index in the thread map (not array, because maps can shrink more efficiently when elements are removed)

it's still not guaranteed to have the exact same order wanted but it would look more random than the version with all threads free.

Another slow but random-ish solution would be sleeping every new thread(person) with randomized amount of time. Then they'd wake up automatically in the order of their predefined waiting time (ordered by OS, I guess, so not guaranteed always).

create person thread
generate random number = x
sleep the new thread with x seconds
automatically wakes up in randomized order with other threads

